# Derived datatypes vs Abstract Datatypes

Tags: c++, abstract-data-type

While reading for `c++`, I came across, derived data types such as `array`, `struct`, `unions` etc. However we also study about `stacks`, `queues`, `binary search tree` , `trees` as `ADT`.

I wonder, are these `ADT` derived datatypes too?

Comment: Uhm, where did you read about array, structs etc. being *derived* types? What was the context? What was the book/sites meaning of the term "derived"?

Comment: ADT isn't a C++ language construct. It's more like a specification of how a data type should behave (more like a model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays, structs, unions or pointers are derived types that C++ inherited from C. They allow to create new data types from basic types (`int`, `long`, `float`...).

In C++ you also have the Standard Template Library (STL), which are abstract types. They differ from derived types in that they are classes that use [templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates).

So, answering your questions, abstract types are more powerful than derived types because the template mechanism has richer semantics. For instance, in C++ you can have an abstract struct:

```c
template <typename T> 
struct mytype { 
    T value;
};
```

Comment: This answers my question. Thanks, dude